# How to assign value to unshared_at for a file using BOX API v2.0

Tags: timestamp, box-api

I am trying to create a 'shared link' for a file uploaded. Using BOX API, I am sending a request with body as:

{"shared_link": {"access": "open","unshared_at":1347215400,"permissions": {"download": true, "preview": false }} }

However, it does not seem to work!??? ( of course, 1347215400 being unix-timestamp value corresponding to some time on Sep 9, 2012 )

The request without the unshared_at parameter, like

{"shared_link": {"access": "open","permissions": {"download": true, "preview": false }} }

works and sets the relevant attribute values as expected.

Have actually also tried various other possible timestamp formats but without success. API documentation does mention the format in which timestamps values are returned but does not say anything about what format it expects for setting the value!

Anyone out there to help?

Answer (score 0):

Please send in the timestamp values as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The documentation was just updated to indicate this more clearly.